# Django ManyToManyField SystemCheckError

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Professional(models.Model):
    ...
    favoriting_customers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'customers.Customer', blank=True,
        through='favorites.FavoriteProfessional')

    recommending_customers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'customers.Customer', blank=True,
        through='recommendations.ProfessionalRecommendation')
```

I get no errors when I delete on of the ManyToMany fields. However, I get SystemCheckError when I run 'python manage.py makemigrations'.

ERRORS:
professionals.Professional.favoriting_customers: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Professional.favoriting_customers' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Professional.recommending_customers'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Professional.favoriting_customers' or 'Professional.recommending_customers'.
professionals.Professional.recommending_customers: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Professional.recommending_customers' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Professional.favoriting_customers'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Professional.recommending_customers' or 'Professional.favoriting_customers'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the *HINT*, you need to use [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to avoid clashes on [backward relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). You are going to need this every time you have two fields in the same model with a relation to the same object (`customers.Customer` in your case).

You can try something like this:

```
class Professional(models.Model):
    ...
    favoriting_customers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'customers.Customer', blank=True,
        through='favorites.FavoriteProfessional',
        related_name='favorites'
    )

    recommending_customers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'customers.Customer', blank=True,
        through='recommendations.ProfessionalRecommendation',
        related_name='recommendations'
    )
```

If you are not interested in backward relation to `Professional` table, you can disable it by using `'+'` as the `related_name`:

```
class Professional(models.Model):
    ...
    favoriting_customers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'customers.Customer', blank=True,
        through='favorites.FavoriteProfessional',
        related_name='+'
    )

    recommending_customers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'customers.Customer', blank=True,
        through='recommendations.ProfessionalRecommendation',
        related_name='+'
    )
```

Also, you should [be careful with related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name)